# Angular js Replace month number with month name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a date time string object in a html. The format of date time string is mm/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss
Based upon the month number I am trying to get month name.

I tried following things,

1. I cannot put .getMonth() as it string.
2. `<div ng-switch="item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime.split("/")[0]">`
   JavaScript is not working in angular switch expression.
3. Below is not working `<span class="calendar_mon">{{item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime.split("/")[0]=="12"?"December"}}</span>`
4. All I can do is write some js operations in the object.

Any help?

Comment: You could have `getMonth` as function inside your `ng-switch` directive like `ng-switch="getMonth(item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime)"` & then getMonth will return a string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in your controller that gets the date as param, find the month and returns the month name and use it in the controller like:

```
<span class="calendar_mon">
     {{someFunction(item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime)}}
</span>
```

then in your controller do the logic you used above:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(stringDate) {
  var month = stringDate.split("/")[0];
  var returnMonth;

  switch(month) {
     case "01": returnMonth = "January"; break;
     case "02": returnMonth = "February"; break;
     case "03": returnMonth = "March"; break;
     case "04": returnMonth = "April"; break;
     case "05": returnMonth = "May"; break;
     case "06": returnMonth = "June"; break;
     case "07": returnMonth = "July"; break;
     case "08": returnMonth = "August"; break;
     case "09": returnMonth = "September"; break;
     case "10": returnMonth = "October"; break;
     case "11": returnMonth = "November"; break;
     case "12": returnMonth = "December"; break;
  }

   return returnMonth;
}
```

or even better, parse the date and get the month:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(stringDate) {
      var parsedDate = new Date(stringDate);
      var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

      return months[parsedDate.getMonth()];
);
```

or another way:

```
{{ someFunction(item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime) | date: "MMMM"}}
```

then the function in the controller, would look like:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(dateString) {
     // you should add checks here if "dateString.split("/")[0]" returns anything
    return new Date(dateString.split("/")[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arber. I used the solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function in your controller that returns the month.

```
$scope.getMonthString = function(dateString){
   return $filter('date')(new Date(dateString), 'MMMM');
};
```

Then your HTML will be

```
<span>
    {{getMonthString(item.applicationData.EventStartDateTime)}}
</span>
```

Comment: Vetrivelmurugan, don't forget to inject $filter if you use this option :)